# Is there anything to be gained by upgrading Rg.Plugins.Popup from release: 1.2.0.223 to 2.0.0.2 when used in Xamarin Forms?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

My code is currently using Version 1.2.0.223 but I see now there is another release: 2.0.0.2

https://github.com/rotorgames/Rg.Plugins.Popup

Is there anyone who is using this that's familiar enough with the product to tell me if there's any differences between the two for a person like me who is using it with Xamarin Forms.

I do see the release notes but they are just bullet one liners and the changes / benefits are not at all clear to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Amongst many things like bug fixes and better error handling to reduce crashes, the major update is that they migrated to AndroidX to support it in Xamarin solutions that use AndroidX.

If you are looking to migrate your android project to android X, you will need to update that package.

Answer (score 0):

Having a look at its [GitHub Source code link](https://github.com/rotorgames/Rg.Plugins.Popup/releases) , you will know what's new feature in the new version.

[image]

If cureent version is `1.2.0.223` , the version of `2.0.0.2` will contatin the feature of `2.0.0` .

**2.0.0** :

- Multi-target based
- WPF support
- Tizen support
- Multiple bug fixes

**2.0.0.2** :

- Android 9.0 backwards compatible

Now you will know that the version of `2.0.0.2` will contain the above new features .